# How can I avoid code duplication

Tags: c#

I have the follwoing code and I would like to write it in a way that I have minimum lines of code and the work is done the same way.  How can  I do that?

```
List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();
categoryList = Category.LoadForProject(project.ID).ToList();
List<string> categories = new List<string>(Categories);
IList<Category> currentCategories = Category.LoadForProject(project.ID).ToList();
if (currentCategories != null)
{
    foreach (var existingCategories in currentCategories)
    {
        if (categories.Contains(existingCategories.Name))
           categories.Remove(existingCategories.Name);
        else
            existingCategories.Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
    }
    foreach (string item in categories)
    {
        Category category = new Category(project, item.ToString());
        category.Project = project;
        category.Save();
   }
}
```

---

```
List<string> priorities = new List<string>(Priorities);
IList<Priority> currentPriorities = Priority.LoadForProject(project.ID).ToList();
if (currentPriorities != null)
{
   foreach (var existingPriorities in currentPriorities)
   {
       if (priorities.Contains(existingPriorities.Name))
           priorities.Remove(existingPriorities.Name);
       else
           existingPriorities.Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
   }
   foreach (string item in priorities)
   {
       Priority priority = new Priority(project, item.ToString());
       priority.Project = project;
       priority.Save();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
public IList<T> DoYourThing<T>(IList<T> items, IList<T> currentItems, Project project) where T : CommonBaseType
{
  if (currentItems != null)
  {
    foreach (var existingItem in currentItems)
    {
      if (items.Contains(existingItem.Name))
        items.Remove(existingItem.Name);
      else
        existingItems.Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
    }
    foreach (string item in items)
    {
      T newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] {project, item.ToString()}) as T;
      newItem.Project = project;
      newItem.Save();
    }
  }

  return currentItems;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var currentCategories = DoYourThing(Categories.ToList(), Category.LoadForProject(project.ID).ToList());
var currentProjects = DoYourThing(Priorities.ToList(), Priority.LoadForProject(project.ID).ToList());
```

Finally, you should note two things in particular:
First, there is a generic condition on the function `where T : CommonBaseType`.  I am assuming that Category and Project have a common base type or interface that includes Name.   If not, you should get rid of the condition and use Dynamic to get at Name.

Second, I am using Activator.Create to create the class for you.  This is the tricky part that makes it difficult to figure out, if you don't know that trick

Good luck!

Comment: Generics is a nice solution... your call would need to add the type wouldn't it, i.e. `var currentCategories = DoYourThing<Category>(Categories.ToList(), Category.LoadForProject(project.ID).ToList());`?

Comment: @Lasarus: Nope. When the type can be inferred by the parameters (as in this case), the type declaration on the method is redundant. :)

Comment: @Brian Genisio your right that is impossibly hard to come by if you don't understand the Activator.Create part. This is simple Genius.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `Activator.CreateInstance` rather than `Activator.Create`?

Comment: If you did want to avoid the `Activator.CreateInstance` call in favor of a constructor that can be verified at compile-time, you can pass in a 'builder' parameter of type `Func<Project,string,T>`, which can be easily specified by the caller of the method with a lambda syntax: `(p,s) => new Category(p,s)`  This also provides additional flexibility to the caller, if they'd like to build some stub or descended version of your Category, for example.

Comment: Thanks, a lot for replying. I am new to C#. Could you please give me the piece of code using dynamic as I am not having a common base. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Make Priority and Category implement the same Interface or derive from a class with the common properties in it (i.e. .Project, .Name and .Save). Then use that Interface or base class as the type of your function and you will be able to pass collections of both classes to it.

Comment: @Lazarus was halfway though writing code for it when I saw @Brian Genisio has illustrated the point nicely!

Answer (score 1):

Okay,
as far as i understood, you want to add the categories/priorities of the "new" list, that are not existant in the repository.

make that.

```
public void SaveNewItems<T>(IList<string> newList, IList<T> currentList, string project)
    where T: new(), IStoreableItem
{
    //find only new items
    var toAdd = from itemName in newList
                where !currentList.Contains(i => i.Name = itemName)
                select new T {
                    Name = itemName,
                    Project = project
                };


    //find items to delete
    var toDelete = from item in currentList
                   where !newList.Contains(item.Name)
                   select item;

    toAdd.ToList().ForEach(item => item.Save());
    toDelete.ToList().ForEach(item => item.Delete());
}
```

Category and Prio must derive from IStoreableItem that contains the name, project, and save/delete method.

Answer (score 0):

If `Priority` and `Category` are either both derived from the same base class with a common set of methods / properties, or implement the same interface then yes, you can.  You will just need to replace the specific references to `Priority` and `Category` with references to either that base class or interface (as applicable).

There's a few minor code differences (like the `List<string>(Categories)` in the first code block) that you will have to think about how to handle, but most of the code will just fall into place once the ancestor / interface question is settled.

Comment: I don't think this is a case for inheritance as the class hierarchy wouldn't make sense. You could create an arbitrary base class but it wouldn't follow the spirit of being a common ancestor to the child classes. An interface makes much more sense here to provide a common 'API' to disparate classes.

Answer (score 0):

I find `dynamic` very useful for sets of types that expose the same property, but don't implement the same interface.

Iterate through the list with `foreach(dynamic d in myList)... d.Name...`, wrap it into a method, and pass different `IList<object>` instances (categories or priorities).

Requires C# 4.0.

Comment: That just feels like cheating to me ;-)

Comment: same as Jouke. that is just lazy here. dynamic is not intended that you do not need to define interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, a lot for replying.  I am new to C#.  Could you please give me the piece of code using dynamic.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Priority and Category derive from the same base class... and then you could do something along the lines of:

```
public void ProcessLists<ItemType>(Func<int, IEnumerable<ItemType>> Loader) whereItemType : CommonBase, new() {
List<string> items = new List<string>();
IList<ItemType> currentItems = Loader(project.ID).ToList();
if (currentItems != null) {
    foreach (var existingItem in currentItems) {
        if (items.Contains(existingItem.Name))
            items.Remove(existingItem.Name);
        else
            existingItem.Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
    }
    foreach (string item in items) {
        ItemType item = new ItemType();
        item.Project = project
        item.Name = item.ToString();
        item.Save();
    }
}
```

}

Of course, some types (such as the project.ID) are merely guessed and should be replaced with the proper lines.

You can call the function for Priority in this way:

```
ProcessLists<Priority>(id => Priority.LoadForProject(project.ID));
```

Comment: With this solution, you get stuck when you need to call new ItemType, as it needs to be different based on the actual type.  Generics are the way to go here.

Comment: @Brian: Hmmm, I'm afraid I don't see your point. Could you explain it further?

Comment: @Christian: In his two different implementations, he calls new Category(args) and new Project(args).  You can't just call new ItemType().  You won't get the type you expect.

You need to make the method generic, and call Activator.Create(typeof(T), args) to create the correct derivation of ItemType.

Comment: @Brian: Of course I will get the type I expected and need ;) That's what the new()-constraint in the function signature is there for. The only "problem" is that I can't pass the constructor args directly but instead assign them via the properties. And btw... my method is generic ;)

Comment: Doat!  I missed that it is generic... not sure how.  Probably because I am dumb. :)  I get what you are suggesting now.  Sorry about that :)

Comment: No problem ;) I also like your use of Activator.CreateInstance!

Comment: How can I use Activator.CreateInstance with dynamic? Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible, but.. it's not very sexy. I'd rather go with Brian's solution and extend it with a CreateItem-factory parameter.