# How to eliminate duplicate code?

Tags: c#

I have the following codes and I would like to write it in a way that I have minimum duplication of codes.

```
if (Categories != null)
{
    bool flag=false;
    foreach (dynamic usableCat in Category.LoadForProject(project.ID))
    {
        foreach (dynamic catRow in Categories)
        {
            if (usableCat.ID == catRow.ID)
                flag = true;                            
        }
        if (!flag)
        {
            int id = usableCat.ID;
            Category resolution = Category.Load(id);
            resolution.Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
        }
    }
}
if (Priorities != null)
{
    bool flag = false;
    foreach (dynamic usableCat in Priority.LoadForProject(project.ID))
    {
        foreach (dynamic catRow in Priorities)
        {
            if (usableCat.ID == catRow.ID)
                flag = true;
        }
        if (!flag)
        {
            int id = usableCat.ID;
            Priority resolution = Priority.Load(id);
            resolution.Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that Category and priority do not have a common base type or interface that includes ID.

Comment: I assume you don't have access to change the Priority or Category classes?

Comment: In your code example, you're using `dynamic` where it seems you could use `var` (early-binding) instead.  It looks like what you really want is to use `dynamic` to get late-binding semantics, at which point it won't matter that there's no common base type, you can use the `ID` field anyway.  (That is, it sounds like you want to use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) .)

Comment: OP already posted the question in a slightly altered version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203447/how-can-i-avoid-code-duplication/3203570#3203570

Comment: The question is not same as this time I am comparing Lists of objects and there it was looking for a string in a list.

Comment: @user281180: The difference is minimal. You'd be better served asking a question like 'Where can I learn to refactor code?'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me suggest an alternative approach: Instead of factoring out the `flag` thing, use LINQ to remove the *need* for the flag loop:

```
if (Categories != null)
{
    foreach (var usableCat in Category.LoadForProject(project.ID))
    {
       if (!Categories.Any(row => usableCat.ID == row.ID))
            Category.Load(usableCat.ID).Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
    }
}
if (Priorities != null)
{
    foreach (var usablePri in Priority.LoadForProject(project.ID))
    {
        if (!Priorities.Any(row => usablePri.ID == row.ID))
            Priority.Load(usablePri.ID).Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, really helpful, but still my problem to eliminate code duplication is still not solved.

Answer (score 7):

```
void DeleteUsable<Ttype>(IEnumerable<Ttype> usables, IEnumerable<Ttype> collection, Func<int, Ttype> load)
{
     bool flag = false;
     foreach (dynamic usableCat in usables)
                {
                    foreach (dynamic catRow in collection)
                    {
                        if (usableCat.ID == catRow.ID)
                            flag = true;
                    }
                    if (!flag)
                    {
                        int id = usableCat.ID;
                        Ttype resolution = load(id);
                        resolution.Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
                    }
                }
}
```

Edit:
call it:

```
if (Categories != null) 
   DeleteUsable(Category.LoadForProject(project.ID), Categories, Categoriy.Load); 
if (Priorities != null) 
   DeleteUsables(Priority.LoadForProject(project.ID), Priorities, Priority.Load);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to call the function with the given example?

Comment: You won't be able to call the Delete-method.

Comment: What is category.Load andpriority.Load?

Comment: @user281180: the static methods you called in your code. Priority.Load(id)...


@Christian: why?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a method like this (since you have access to dynamic types):

```
void DeleteUsables(dynamic usablesResource, dynamic usablesCatalog)
{
    bool flag = false;
    foreach (dynamic usableCat in usablesCatalog.LoadForProject(project.ID))
    {
        foreach (dynamic catRow in usablesResource)
        {
            if (usableCat.ID == catRow.ID)
                flag = true;                            
        }
        if (!flag)
        {
            int id = usableCat.ID;
            dynamic resolution = usablesCatalog.Load(id);
            resolution.Delete(Services.UserServices.User);
        }
    }

}
```

which you would then call like this:

```
if (Categories != null)
{
    DeleteUsables(Categories, Category)
}
if (Priorities != null)
{
    DeleteUsables(Priorities, Priority)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am having the error:

'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'LoadForProject'

Comment: It looks like RCIX overlooked that `Category` and `Categories` are two different things in your project. If `Category` is an object (rather than a class), you can pass it as an additional dynamic parameter.

Comment: @Heinzi: thanks, i fixed it. @user: there you go, i couldn't think up a good name for the second parameter though. Perhaps you would be able to?

Comment: @Heinzi : I`m having the error message Error 3 API.Category' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' C:\MvcUI\Models\ProjectModel.cs 230 43 MvcUI

Comment: Well, if `Category` and `Priority` are types, you are a bit out of luck: `dynamic` does not support invocation of static members. There is a workaround for this, but it's not trivial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/10/23/using-c-dynamic-to-call-static-members.aspx